# A word for someone who you feel uncomfortable with

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I need to find a word for someone who you feel uncomfortable with - like awkward. Someone who you like, but can't really have a normal and comfortable conversation with. Maybe even someone who makes you feel self-conscious, though that's not what I'm really aiming for...

Comment: Is this a quality of the person (i.e. - does *everyone else* feel awkward with them?). Or is it something peculiar to the specific relationship/interaction? (as in, *Word for someone you like and feel relaxed with* = ***friend***).

Comment: I'd go with "discomfiting" which means you are sort of disturbed by a person, a little knocked off balance. For example, I know someone who is supposed to be a friend, but fancies me. I do not fancy him back, mostly because he is weird, not physically attractive to me, and has a peculiar voice and mannerisms. I thought that I gave him enough hints that I was not interested but he still persists, and has gone through the roof with his demands. He is one of those people who unfortunately get under your skin, and has started making extremely snide and patronizing remarks, to the extent that I am

Comment: I think you are searching for a noun?  Please clarify.

Comment: A pain in the neck/ass.

Answer (score 5):

I used to work alongside such a person. He was *okay*, and acted friendly enough but there was something about him which made me internally cringe whenever we exchanged words. Perhaps it was his excessive enthusiasm that I found most irritating, in any case I always had an excuse not to join him for a coffee.

There are some people you do not want to be alone with, and not necessarily because you fear for your personal safety but because they are ***unnerving***, and you feel ***uneasy*** in their company.

> Her [**unnerving habit**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unnerving) of
>   touching people she was speaking to
>
> [**uneasy**:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/uneasy) awkward or unsure
>   in manner; *uneasy with strangers.*

Answer (score 4):

> [***unsettling***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unsettling) *: having the effect of upsetting, disturbing, or discomposing*

[A Google Books example](http://books.google.com/books?id=R8Oc45WkWrQC&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=%22I+find+him+unsettling%22&source=bl&ots=6KIHODoGJ_&sig=NEtb6rMnQLGzkON6D2gP97XApTM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=flSpUrGhBcT4yAH2-4CwAw&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22I%20find%20him%20unsettling%22&f=false):

> What I mean is, what do you *really* know about him?  **I find him unsettling**.  He's creepy. That woman Justine is scared of him.

Comment: That doesn't really match the OP's description of "someone who you like, but can't really have a normal and comfortable conversation with."

Comment: @starwed- what do you find that doesn't match? The definition or the example I provided?  I think that the OP asked for *uncomfortable and awkward* and I think *upsetting, disturbing and discomposing* are just that.  If I really liked someone but always felt extremely nervous around them I would describe that as feeling a little unsettled every time I was around that person.

Answer (score 1):

FRENEMY. I hope that helps  :)

Comment: -1: i) not really what the OP is asking for, ii) you give no definition iii) you give no example of usage and iv) that's just a horribly ugly word though I can hardly blame you for that.

Comment: Never heard of such a word.

Comment: @WS2 it [exists](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/frenemy), unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **[intimidating](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/intimidating)**

> inspiring nervousness or fear:
>
> *He was a huge, intimidating figure.*
>
> *A courtroom is a frightening and intimidating place for child witnesses.*
>
> *The trial in an adult court was severely intimidating for the eleven-year-old child.*

Answer (score 0):

I would personally say that my friend is a **bummer**.

A psychologist might say that your friend is **toxic**.

In France I often hear **ami de cour**.